# runtime error (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c

can anyone tell me whats wrong in the following program that accepts 1 or 2 digit integers untill it encounters the number 42 after which it prints the previously entered numbers??when i upload this to the sphere online judge site it says  compilation successful but runtime error  (SIGSEGV).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  FILE *fp;
  fp=fopen("\\db.txt","w+");
  if(fp==NULL)
  {
   printf("file not exitsts and cant be created");
   system("exit");
  }
  while(1)
  {
   scanf("%d",&i);
   if(i==42)
   break;
   else
   {
    fprintf(fp,"%d\n",i); 
   }    
  }
  fclose(fp);
  fp=fopen("\\db.txt","r+");
  if(fp==NULL)
  {
   printf("file not exitsts and cant be created");
   system("exit");
  }
  fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
  printf("%d\n",i); 
  while((!feof(fp)))
  {
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&i);
    if(!feof(fp))
    printf("%d\n",i);                
  }

  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, don't use `<pre>` to mark code, indent it by four spaces. Then we get syntax coloring _and_ don't have any HTML interference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to answer this: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/TEST/ . This problem certainly does not require you to read or write anything from a file, and their server may not allow you to open files on its disk. Even if it does, you're trying to use a windows-style path (with a backslash) on what may be a non-Windows server. And even if it does allow file creation and windows-style path separation, you are trying to create your file in the filesystem root directory, and they almost certainly do not allow file creation *there*.

Combined with the `system("exit")` issue that everyone pointed out where it doesn't actually exit the program, this will cause you to receive a NULL file pointer and crash when you try to use it.

Re-read the problem description - you're over-thinking it. It doesn't say anywhere that you have to wait until you get a 42 to print out the other numbers. All you have to do is print back what is entered until you get a 42. That should make the solution much simpler. It's not supposed to be even a mildly challenging problem; it's just supposed to familiarize you with their system.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you think:

```
system("exit");
```

will do, but the way to exit a program in C is:

```
exit(1);
```

Comment: is exit(1) not only for the case of error? a normal exit should be exit(0); right?

Comment: The system("exit") expression in the original is in an error-handling block.

Comment: C standard specifies three standard error codes: 0, ERROR_SUCCESS and ERROR_FAILURE. Normal exit is 0 or ERROR_SUCCESS.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
system("exit");
```

with

```
exit(1);
```

or, because you're already in `main`:

```
return 1;
```

I suspect the SIGSEGV is caused because you cannot write to the file `\\db.txt`, but the program continues because `system("exit")` is not causing it to terminate.

On an semi-related note, SIGSEGV is usually a Unix signal, and path separators on Unix are `/` rather than `\`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely the cause of the SEGV, but I guess it is because the input doesn't match what you expect. In any case, this line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
system("exit");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. at which line do you receive the error?
2. is your empty #include intended? i think it should mean #include
3. have you got the error for every input or just for 42?

regards

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEGV` is an access violation error, which indicates a `null` pointer. Since `system("exit")` isn't doing anything, `fp` is getting set to `null`, and then when you try to use that pointer (for example with `fprintf()`)... boom, your program crashes.

Replace `system("exit")` with `return 1` (or whatever error code you desire), that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:8: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘system’
$ ./test 
1 
2
3
10
42
1
2
3
10
```

[image: Could not reproduce]

But yes, I do agree that the `system("exit")` does not what you expect. What you are exiting from, with that call, is a subshell that is spawned by your program, and then goes on. From the `system` man page

> The system() function hands the
>   argument command to the command
>   interpreter sh(1).  The calling
>   process waits for the shell to finish
>   executing the command, ignoring SIGINT
>   and SIGQUIT, and blocking SIGCHLD.

Comment: Try running the program from a directory where the current user does not have permission to create files. It crashes on the first input, as expected.